# WebRequest: Query string data vs x-www-form-urlencoded content

Tags: c#, query-string, webrequest

I am trying to call Google's OAuth2 authentication service as per these instructions: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ForDevices

I put all of the required parameters into the query string and sent the request. This worked for the "Obtaining a user code" section but not for the "Obtaining Access and Refresh Tokens" section.

After much playing around and getting 400 Bad Request errors, I found that, instead of putting the data in the query string, you can create a request with a FormUrlEncodedContent and send the data through as content with application\x-www-form-urlencoded Content-Type.

Here is the code before:

```
var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();
requestMessage.Method = "POST";
requestMessage.RequestUri = new Uri(fullUrl);
```

Where fullUrl is something like:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/device/code?client_id=812741506391-h38jh0j4fv0ce1krdkiq0hfvt6n5amrf.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile
```

And the new code is:

```
var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();
requestMessage.Method = "POST";
requestMessage.RequestUri = new Uri(url);
requestMessage.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(CreateDictionary(queryStringNames, queryStringValues));
```

Where url is:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/device/code
```

and queryStringNames and queryStringValues are string arrays of the names and values of the required parameters.

What is the difference between these two methods? Is it safe to assume that all POST calls can use the URL Encoded Content requests instead of putting the data in the query string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, POST requests do not need query string but it is still subjected to Server's logic implementation. In case of OAuth which is quite known standard and they do follow good practice, it is safe to use form encoded data unless mentioned explicitly in API to send Parameter as query string.

Query String & Post data are two different set of parameters. If server is expecting Query string then you must send query string only. It all depends on how server side logic is implemented. You can not use them alternatively. Most API documentation specify clearly what are they expecting.